# Is there a Java class for "infinitely" accurate numbers?

Tags: java, numbers, scientific-computing

I was thinking of writing a class (actually a set of classes with one public generic class) for "infinite" integers, that stores fractions as fractions (no floating points) and could handle imaginary numbers and the like. Before I start, does this already exist?

Comment: I struggle to believe you are the first person with these requirements; so I can't believe it doesn't exist somewhere. But questions asking us to find or recommend libraries are off-topic.

Comment: Take a look at Apache Commons' [Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) libraries. It already has a pretty good amount of stuff to go by. That said, if you think you can do better than those guys, then go for it.

Comment: That said, @AndyTurner is right - this is not really the place to ask if there is a library that does X. Usually there are, but those answers wouldn't be good because they spoil as libraries get deprecated and rereleased.

Comment: You can easily write a class to store a numerator and a denominator, but IEEE754 floating point can only be so accurate.

Comment: @matoni: You can represent imaginary numbers in `BigDecimal`?

Comment: @AndyTurner The OP actually did not ask for a *library*. The essense of the question is "how do I represent infinitely accurate numbers in Java" which is OK in my book. And you don't need a library for that.

Answer (score 3):

At risk of sounding pedantic: you've described several sets of numbers at once. Integers are just the positive and negative whole numbers, including zero. Fractions are the rational numbers, a superset of the integers. Imaginary numbers are another set, and the infinities are in the hyperreal and surreal sets.

The [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class may be useful for storing your huge integers. It would be relatively easy to build a wrapper class with the sum of rational numbers (expressed as some BigInteger p over another BigInteger q), and you could extend these to have a rational part, imaginary part, infinitesimal part, and infinitely large part. This doesn't address irrational numbers, though.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're just looking for [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) or [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) which can handle integers with arbitrary length or precision.

Concerning "imaginary numbers", I guess you're talking about complex numbers. Check [Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) for that.